# Simulate a couple of clients calling a single Server class in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, client, server

I intend to test a `Server` class to see how it handles concurrent reads and writes using direct calls to the server class, nothing more fancy. I have a Server API that has two functions.

```
int fetch(int key);

void push(int key, int value);
```

How do I create multiple clients making calls to the server? Do I just start multiple threads of a `Client` class implementing `Runnable` that call the functions using a static server variable within `run()`?

Comment: Having multiple threads accessing one single instance of your server object might be incorrect as many client-side server APIs are not thread safe. Please tell us more about your client-server architecture. Which technology do you use for communication? RMI, JAX-RS, HTTP, web services, something proprietary, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly, you should have multiple clients running at the same time on different threads, and they should call the same server object.

Note that with this kind of testing there is no guarantee that you find all the bugs. You should still reason about the thread safety of your code. Possibly you could also use more sophisticated concurrent testing frameworks like [multithreadedtc](https://code.google.com/p/multithreadedtc/)

Comment: I doubt that this will do. Concurrently accessing one single Server object might just test if the client-side server representation is thread-safe (which often is not the case). It heavily depends on the client-server architecture and technology that is used!

Comment: @isnot2bad Yes. Note that I did not say that this will be enough. The question was "How do I create multiple clients making calls to the server?"

Comment: Yes, but it might be wrong if the server object (that represents the server on client side) is not thread safe. If that's the case, it is important to create a server instance per client.